# Does python timeit consider setup in the count

Tags: python, timeit

I'm using python timeit to see how long it takes for a function to run.

```
    setup = '''from __main__ import my_func
    import random
    l = list(range(10000))
    random.shuffle(l)'''
    timeit.timeit('my_func(l)', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

the results I'm getting are bigger than a 'normal' check with datetime.
Does timeit also count the time the setup takes, and if so - how can I disable it?

Comment: Please include your setup with datetime and the results of both.

Comment: Show us the results. Are they 1000 times bigger? Timeit returns the [time taken for `number=1000` executions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit). And no, the setup phase is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `my_func(l)` mutate `l`? That could affect the timings.

`timeit` will run the setup once and reuse the objects created by the setup each time it calls the code that is to be timed. Also it can call the code a few times to gauge roughly how fast it runs and choose the number of iterations before the actual timed run (though not when you've specified the number of runs yourself). That would mean if there is an initial fast run it won't be included in the timed results.

For example if `my_func()` was a badly written quicksort function it might run quickly when you call it on a shuffled list and very very slowly when you call it again with a (now sorted) list. `timeit` would only measure the very slow calls.

Comment: thank you very much! :)it does mutate the list, I didn't realize that the setup only runs once, that does affect my results

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#python-interface) say:

> The execution time of setup is excluded from the overall timed
>   execution run.

Answer (score 0):

The Python 2.0 [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) are pretty clear that the setup statement is not timed:

> Time number executions of the main statement. This executes the setup
>   statement once, and then returns the time it takes to execute the main
>   statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float.

But if you're not sure, put a big, slow process into the setup statement and test to see what difference it makes.